# OFDM with frequency domain LMS-based channel estimation

Tags: digital-communications, frequency-response, digital-filters, ofdm, lms

For OFDM, we usually perform least-square (LS) channel estimation using a set of training symbols. We usually do LS channel estimation per subcarrier in the frequency domain as follows:
$$
\hat H_{LS}[k] = Y[k]/X[k]
$$
where $\hat H_{LS}[k]$ is the estimated channel (in frequency domain) for subcarrier $k$, $Y[k]$ is the data received on subcarrier $k$, and $X[k]$ is the training symbol transmitted on subcarrier $k$. The estimated channel response can be regarded as a single TAP (for each subcarrier).

Instead of doing channel estimation and equalization in the frequency domain, we can do them in the time domain. LMS algorithm (with adaptive filters) can be used to accomplish this.

I am wondering if we can use the LMS algorithm in the frequency domain where we use a standalone frequency domain LMS for each subcarrier. So, after FFT, for each subcarrier, we run LMS algorithm to estimate the filter coefficients in the frequency domain (We do this for each subcarrier).

I am wondering if this is possible to be done?, has it been done already? any available resources?

Thanks

Comment: what would be the advantage of doing this? Because the way you design your OFDM system, each subcarrier individually, by design, is flat, and can be corrected by a single elementary arithmetic operation in the frequency domain. Thus, the "filter coefficients in the frequency domain" are just a single number. Don't really see the point where you could introduce an LMS there?

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, having second thoughts, I totally agree with you. I was just curious to know if frequency domain LMS is used in OFDM. Because I am aware that time domain channel estimation/equalization (like LMS) is not recommended for OFDM because the whole point of OFDM is avoiding time domain channel estimation. I will close my question as it may mislead other researchers. Thank you for your response

Comment: I don't know whether you should do that! I might not 100% understand what you're getting at, because:

Comment: Even in OFDM, the single taps, they need to be extra- and interpolated: you don't want to send pilot symbols all the time on all subcarriers, so you need to extrapolate from past pilots on the individual subcarrier, and interpolate from pilots on neighboring subcarriers. To that end, systems like 4G/5G distribute their pilots across the time/subcarrier plane – an LMS-style algorithm might be a way of doing that. Also, don't forget that even that single coefficient on a subcarrier might vary over time, and following that channel variance might also be done with such techniques.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you very much

Comment: Broadly speaking your idea is similar to the question in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59664. Basically having the optimal filter in a given band of the spectrum.